# php mysql insert X number of multiple rows with 1 query

Tags: php, mysql

i want to do insert as many rows as the number in `$add_rows = $_POST['add-rows']` to a table. for what i'm working now, i need 32 rows.  how do i go about making the SQL VALUES part a loop so it enters 32 rows??

this is my form

```
<form>
<input name="add-name" id="add-name" type="text" value="">
<input name="add-start" id="add-start" type="text" value="">
<input name="add-end" id="add-end" type="text" value="">
<input name="add-rows" id="add-rows" type="text" value="">
<input name="add-submit" id="add-submit" type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

below are the values i'll be posting from the form, the rest of values can be setas NULL

```
$add_name = $_POST['add-name'];
$add_start = $_POST['add-start'];
$add_end = $_POST['add-end'];
$add_rows = $_POST['add-rows']; //in this case, the value is 32
```

this is the query... i'd need to enter 32 VALUES.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table position, name, start, end, code, one, two, three, four, five, six) 
VALUES (NULL, '$add_name', '$add_start', '$add_end', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)")
or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: As a side note: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions anymore and consider switching to MySQLi oder PDO instead.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your SQL statement (missing parenthesis after the table name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you 32 rows.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (position, name, start, end, code, one, two, three, four, five, six) 
VALUES (NULL, '$add_name', '$add_start', '$add_end', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)"
     . str_repeat(", (NULL, '$add_name', '$add_start', '$add_end', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)", $add_rows - 1)
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: thanks. it worked but for some reason it's inserting an extra blank row..?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table position, name, start, end, code, one, two, three, four, five, six) 
VALUES (NULL, '$add_name', '$add_start', '$add_end', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(NULL, '$add_name', '$add_start', '$add_end', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(NULL, '$add_name', '$add_start', '$add_end', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(NULL, '$add_name', '$add_start', '$add_end', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)")
or die(mysql_error());
```

here there's only  4 lines, but you cant do it for 32 lines.

you can construct also the request in a loop (to set different variables values)
Don't forget the comma bewteen each value (but there's no comma at the end of the last line).

Answer (score 0):

Use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) along with a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php):

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=example', $user, $pass);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO table (position, name, start, end, code, one, two, three, four, five, six) VALUES (NULL, :add_name, :add_start, :add_end, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)");
$stmt->bindParam(':add_name', $add_name);
$stmt->bindParam(':add_start', $add_start);
$stmt->bindParam(':add_end', $add_end);

for ($i = 0; $i < $add_rows; $i++) {
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

This has the added benefit of hardening your query against SQL injection attacks. Your question and other answers (at the time of writing) are using unescaped $_POST values directly in the query.

Comment: i have issues using PDO. i'd like to try it but everytime i use it, something breaks. thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

The column names need to be between parenthesis. I think you need to see the syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

I think this is a question & answers site not a give me this syntax site.
@Azukah Have a look at this syntax for learning. And in case you just want the syntax, check other answers.

:)

Comment: sorry about the syntax. i messed it up when retyping. will double check b4 posting. thanks!